# React with TypeScript: how to access HOC methods in new coponent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

HI I have an interface for a props and a state:

```
interface IOffersProps
{
    nextStep: () => void;
    step: number
}

export default IOffersProps

interface IOffersState
{}

export default IOffersState;
```

I created a HOC, that has for example a myhocMethod method, like below:

```
const addOffersLogic = <TProp extends IOffersProps, TState extends IOffersState>(Component: React.ComponentType<TProp> | React.StatelessComponent<TProp>) =>

    class OffersBase extends React.Component<TProp & IOffersProps, TState & IOffersState>
    {
        constructor(props: TProp & IOffersProps)
        {
            super(props);

            this.myhocMethod= this.myhocMethod.bind(this);
        }

        myhocMethod= (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement, MouseEvent>) : void =>
        {
            //do something
        };

        render()
        {
            return(
                <Component {...this.props} />
            );
          }
    }

export default addOffersLogic;
```

Now in my new component, I can't access **myhocMethod** method. I am trying do access it like this.

```
class OffersWithoutLogicDesktop extends React.Component<IOffersProps & WithStyles<typeof styles>, IOffersState>
{
    constructor(props: IOffersProps & WithStyles<typeof styles>)
    {
        super(props);
    }

    render()
    {
        const css = this.props.classes;

        const Body = () =>
            <StackPanel>
                <HorizontalLinearStepper step={this.props.step} />
                Offers
                <Button
                    color="primary"
                    className={css.button}
                    onClick={this.myhocMethod}>
                    Continue
                </Button>
                <Footer />
            </StackPanel>

        return Body();
    }
}

const OffersDesktop = addOffersLogic(OffersWithoutLogicDesktop);
```

My goal is to place the same logic in one file.
thnx

Comment: *using HOC is batter then inheritance because of the nature of the React ecosystem* - then this HOC doesn't make it any better because it still uses inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access a method defined in the HOC you need to pass it as props to the component that is wrapped with the HOC

```
const addOffersLogic = <TProp extends IOffersProps, TState extends IOffersState>(Component: React.ComponentType<TProp> | React.StatelessComponent<TProp>) =>

    class OffersBase extends React.Component<TProp & IOffersProps, TState & IOffersState>
    {
        constructor(props: TProp & IOffersProps)
        {
            super(props);

            this.myhocMethod= this.myhocMethod.bind(this);
        }

        myhocMethod= (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement, MouseEvent>) : void =>
        {
            //do something
        };

        render()
        {
            return(
                <Component {...this.props} myhocMethod={this.myhocMethod}/>
            );
          }
    }

export default addOffersLogic;
```

---

```
class OffersWithoutLogicDesktop extends React.Component<IOffersProps & WithStyles<typeof styles>, IOffersState>
{
    constructor(props: IOffersProps & WithStyles<typeof styles>)
    {
        super(props);
    }

    render()
    {
        const css = this.props.classes;

        const Body = () =>
            <StackPanel>
                <HorizontalLinearStepper step={this.props.step} />
                Offers
                <Button
                    color="primary"
                    className={css.button}
                    onClick={this.props.myhocMethod}>
                    Continue
                </Button>
                <Footer />
            </StackPanel>

        return Body();
    }
}

const OffersDesktop = addOffersLogic(OffersWithoutLogicDesktop);
```